# Hide background layer on hover, reapers when hovering over <p> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the mixitup library to create a sortable grid. I have an overlaying grid item (.image-over) on top of individual grid items (.mix). When hovering over the grid item the div in the background (with a background image) gets blurred (.mix) and the displayed text is hidden (h1). In the overlaying div a new text is displayed (p.descfirst). When I hover over the new text inside

the text reappears (h1). Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

```css
.mix,
.gap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.mix {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
}

.image-over:hover .mix {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(100%) blur(2px);
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}

.image-over {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 600;
  background: transparent;
}

.mix:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.mix h1 {
  font-weight: 1600;
  font-size: 500em;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.mix:hover h1 {
  display: none;
}

.image-over:hover>p.descfirst {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="./show.html">
    <div class="image-over">
      <p class="descfirst">Progressive</p>
      <div class="mix pink large square" style="background: url('./img/night.jpg')">
        <h1>3 | Test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Update

As the run snippet example is not really working here are some screenshots to demonstrate the problem.

[image: Normal Grid styling with no mouse over]
[image: On hover background image gets blurred, new <p> text appears]
[image: When hovering over <p> element the h1 from underlying area reappears - I want to avoid this]

Comment: When I hover over the 'Progressive' inside the gray, the original 'Progressive' disappears, the gray covers the whole area, and the progressive inside the gray turns white. I am still a bit confused on what exactly is happening that you don't want to happen, and what it is you want to happen

Comment: Hey tyler, please see my update

Comment: I am wondering if, image-over now is above mix, so when you bring that in, you are no longer hovering over mix, but image-over, so <h1> is displayed because mix:hover doesn't apply. You may have to do image-over:hover and navigate to <h1> and do display: none. Otherwise, Pommesloch's answer is good. Binding to a mouseenter/mouseleave event is a great way to do this with Jqeury.

Comment: I wish to help you, I have heavy experience with css, but for me is not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use instead of css a little bit jquery with the mouseenter event.

https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

```
$( "#outer" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( "#inner" ).doStuffHere();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would love to solve the problem in pure css if possible. I will consider your answer if I dont find a pure css solution

Comment: Thanks again, implemented you suggestion